# What is Subsytem Testing for software testing

Tags: junit, mocking, mockito

What exactly is Subsystem testing and is it any different from Integration Testing? Is subsystem testing just testing that the methods work when the parameters are passed to them?

What would be a good subsystem test for this code

```
package server.controller;
import server.storage.ParkedUsers;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.TreeSet;
import server.storage.ParkingSpot;

/**
 * This is the server class that controls all data access and flow.
 * It is also responsible of creating all the parking user objects
 * once it searches them in the FIU Database.
 */
public class AccessControlServer extends Thread
{
    private static ParkedUsers garage = ParkedUsers.instance("garage.txt");
    private final int portNum;
    private PrintWriter sout = null;
    private HashMap<String, PrintWriter> displayConnections 
                                    = new HashMap<String, PrintWriter>();

    /**
     * constructor that initializes the port number variable
     * @param p integer that contains the port number 
     * to which this server will listen to
     */
    public AccessControlServer(int p)
    {
        portNum = p;
        mapConnections();
    }
    /**
     * helper method that maps the text file into the hashmap
     */
    private void mapConnections()
    {

        sout = null;
        displayConnections.put("security", sout);
        for(TreeSet<ParkingSpot> t: garage.values())
            for(ParkingSpot p: t)
            {
                displayConnections.put(p.getParkingNumber(), 
                        p.getPrintWriter());
            }
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        try
        {
            startServer();
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Can't listen on port " + portNum);
        }
    }

    /**
     * initializes the server with the specified port number and 
     * starts listening for connections
     * @throws IOException exception thrown if there is a problem 
     * with the server
     */
    public void startServer() throws IOException
    {
        ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(portNum);
        while(true)
        {
            Socket s = ss.accept();
            Thread t = new Thread(new ConnectionHandler(s));
            t.start();
        }
    }    

    /**
     * method to send a message to a client
     * @param msg sends a string message to the specified client
     * @param pout the print writer connection to the client
     */
    public void sendMessage(String msg, PrintWriter pout)
    {        
        pout.println(msg);
    }

    /**
     * send the security display the status of all the parking spots
     */
    public void sendStatus()
    {
        ArrayList<String> stat = garage.getStatus();
        for(int i = 0;i < stat.size(); i++)
            sendMessage(stat.get(i), sout);
    }

    /**
     * method called to reserve a spot for the user
     * @param spot the spot to be reserved by the user
     * @param id the ID of the user reserving the spot
     */
    synchronized public void reserveSpot(ParkingSpot spot, String id)
    {
        PrintWriter pout = displayConnections.get(spot.getParkingNumber());
        sendMessage("reserve", pout);
        sendMessage(id, pout);
    }
    /**
     * sends the message to the security display that an
     * user has parked on the wrong spot
     * @param msg the message to be sent
     */
    synchronized void wrongUserDetected(String msg)
    {
        if(sout == null)
            return;
        sendMessage("wrong", sout);
        sendMessage(msg, sout);
    }

    /**
     * sends the message to the security display that a 
     * duplicate ID was detected
     * @param msg the message to be sent
     */
    synchronized void duplicateIdFound(String msg, String msg2)
    {
        if(sout == null)
            return;
        sendMessage("duplicate", sout);
        sendMessage(msg, sout);
        sendMessage(msg2, sout);
    }


    /**
     * adds the client to the hashmap containing all the connections
     * @param key the key of the hashmap
     * @param out the print writer connection of the server to the client
     * @param spot the parking spot of the corresponding display
     */
    synchronized private void addDisplay(String key, PrintWriter out, 
            ParkingSpot spot)
    {
        if(!displayConnections.containsKey(key))
            System.out.println( "Invalid spot number.");
        else 
        {
            displayConnections.put(key, out);
            System.out.println( "Connected display to spot successfully.");
            spot.setPrintWriter(out);
        }
    }

    /**
     * removes the display from the hashmap containing all the connections
     * @param key the key of the hashmap
     * @param spot the parking spot of the corresponding display
     */
    synchronized private void removeDisplay(String key, ParkingSpot spot)
    {
        displayConnections.put(key, null);
        spot.setPrintWriter(null);
    } 

    /**
     * accessor
     * @param key the clients spot number
     * @return iff the connection is still alive with the client
     */
    public boolean isConnectionAvailable(String key)
    {
        return (displayConnections.get(key) == null);
    }
    /**
     * private class that handles each connection on a separate thread.
     */
    private class ConnectionHandler implements Runnable
    {
        /*
         * constructor of the private class
         */
        public ConnectionHandler(Socket sock)
        {
            theSocket = sock;
        }

        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            PrintWriter pout = null;
            String spotNumber = "";
            try
            {
                InputStream in = theSocket.getInputStream();
                OutputStream out = theSocket.getOutputStream();

                Scanner scan = new Scanner(in);
                pout = new PrintWriter(out, true);

                spotNumber = scan.nextLine();

                System.out.println(spotNumber);

                if(spotNumber.equalsIgnoreCase("security"))
                    runSecurityDisplay(scan, pout);
                else if(displayConnections.containsKey(spotNumber))
                    runParkingDisplay(scan, pout, spotNumber);


            }

            catch( IOException e )
            {
                System.out.println( "Socket error: " + e + " " +
                                    theSocket.getRemoteSocketAddress( ) );
            }
            finally
            {   
                //removes the display from the list
                removeDisplay(spot.getParkingNumber(), spot);  
                try
                {
                    if( theSocket != null )
                        theSocket.close( );                    
                }
                catch( IOException e )
                {
                    System.out.println( "Socket error: " + e + " " +
                                    theSocket.getRemoteSocketAddress( ) );
                }

            }
        }

        /*
         * runs the thread for the security display client
         */
        private void runSecurityDisplay(Scanner scan, PrintWriter pout)
        {
            if(sout != null)
            {
                sendMessage("another", pout);
                return;
            }
            sout = pout;
            sout.println("successful connection!");

            while(theSocket.isConnected())
            {
                if(theSocket.isClosed())
                    break;
                try 
                {
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                } 
                catch (InterruptedException e) 
                {
                    System.out.println(e);
                }
                sendStatus();
            }

            sout = null;
            displayConnections.put("security", null);




        }
        /**
         * runs the displays threads for each of the parking display clients
         */
        private void runParkingDisplay(Scanner scan, PrintWriter pout, 
                String spotNumber)
        {

            spot = garage.searchBySpotNumber(spotNumber);

            if(!isConnectionAvailable(spotNumber))
            {
                System.out.println("Another display is connected to  spot #" 
                                    + spotNumber);
                sendMessage("another", pout);
                return;
            }

            addDisplay(spotNumber, pout, spot);
            sendMessage(spot.getParkingType(), pout);
            boolean correct = true;
            while(scan.hasNextLine())
            {
                String oneLine = scan.nextLine();

                if(oneLine.equals("leave"))
                {
                    if(correct)
                        spot.removeAssignedUser();
                    else
                        correct = true;
                }

                else if(oneLine.equals("wrong"))
                {
                    wrongUserDetected("Wrong user detected on parking spot #" 
                            + spot.getParkingNumber());
                    if(spot.isAvailable())
                    {
                        ParkingUser user = new GuestUser();
                        spot.assignParkingSpot(user);
                    }
                    else
                        correct = false;
                }
            }


        }        
        private ParkingSpot spot;
        private Socket theSocket;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

These terms are rather "fuzzy"; there is no definition that is universally accepted/spread in the IT world.

I would approach this from the terms themselves:

- A *subsystem* test makes sense in a **large** system that contains many smaller **subsystems**. Example: in my daily job, I am working on some  "subsystem" X that is embedded in a larger delivery. Meaning: X provides distinct, unique features; it has clear boundaries towards other sub systems. But our customer buy that one large product. So "our" sub system tests focuses on testing all the user functionality within X.
- Going from there, *integration tests* for that X are making sure that X works in the context of that large system delivery that we give to our customers.

Your code example contains *one* **class**. For sure that is *never* enough for "system" or "sub system" test. So: you should look into two sorts of testing:

- True unit testing: make sure that this class does its job; when tested in isolation; for example by using mocking frameworks to decouple this class from the non-trivial components it is using.
- Integration/end-to-end testing: ensure that the class is doing its job in the context that is used by the customer.